# Error DartTestGroup isn't a type while running patrol test

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-patrol

While executing patrol test on iOS simulator.
Getting the below error:

```dart
error: integration_test/test_bundle.dart:8:8: Error: Error when reading '../../.pub-cache/git/patrol-4211399e946fa2268527db8b02baeb7959457f25/packages/patrol/lib/src/native/contracts/contracts.pbgrpc.dart': No such file or directory
        import 'package:patrol/src/native/contracts/contracts.pbgrpc.dart';
               ^
        integration_test/test_bundle.dart:51:46: Error: 'DartTestGroup' isn't a type.
          final testExplorationCompleter = Completer<DartTestGroup>();
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
Failed to package /Users/himakondubhotla/StudioProjects/flutter_pca.
note: Building targets in dependency order
```

I have followed the steps provided in the below link for the steps and configured in the same way.

https://patrol.leancode.co/getting-started

```
Pubspec.yaml configuration:
dev_dependencies:
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  leancode_lint: ^3.0.0  
  patrol:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/leancodepl/patrol.git
      path: packages/patrol
      ref: develop
patrol:
  app_name: app name
  android:
    package_name: com.package.name
  ios:
    bundle_id: com.package.name
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest changes in [Patrol v2.3.0](https://pub.dev/packages/patrol/changelog) have renamed some of these classes.

You need to rebuild your generated classes after upgrading, e.g. just run `patrol test` again.

For info, some classes changed, e.g. `DartTestGroup` is now `DartGroupEntry`.

You can glean the changes from this file `packages/patrol_cli/lib/src/test_bundler.dart` when viewing the [changeset for v2.3.0](https://github.com/leancodepl/patrol/pull/1703/files#diff-68e4c1d2dfa683c1175d3b63bec1b05743d4ae99f43dd5c5639113cd0c69b188)